# How to add SoapUI keystore in Java program

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have some other query regarding above topic like How to add WS security header (KeyStore file already generated & added into classpath)  in java programmatically since we are currently executing WsdlProject ( Loading testsuite details from project xml file) with the help of SOAP UI IDE.

Global Setting:

```
SoapUI.getSettings().setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE, "C:/dev/TestKeyStore");
SoapUI.getSettings().setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, "password_123");
```

Sample Code:

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("PROJECT XML PATH");
 List<TestSuite> testSuites = project.getTestSuiteList();
 for (TestSuite suite : testSuites){
    List<TestCase> testCases = suite.getTestCaseList();
        for (TestCase testCase : testCases){
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Awaiting for your response!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you saved settings?

Comment: Yes. In soap request header was blank. While executing SOAPUI xml from Java, the signature was not adding in header.

     <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>

Comment: No, I was asking if `SoapUI.saveSettings();` statement present after the existing two settings?

Comment: Thanks @Rao for replying!

I didn't saved earlier, now i have saved and tested still header was blank.

SoapUI.getSettings().setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE, "C:/dev/TestKeyStore");
SoapUI.getSettings().setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, "password_123");
SoapUI.saveSettings();

Can you guide me here? How to add keystore signature in test case header?

Comment: You did not reply to the question. Would you please confirm?

Comment: Thanks @Rao for replying! I didn't saved earlier, now i have saved and tested still header was blank. SoapUI.getSettings().setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE, "C:/dev/TestKeyStore"); SoapUI.getSettings().setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD‌​, "password_123"); SoapUI.saveSettings(); Can you guide me here? How to add keystore signature in test case header?

Comment: Can you confirm if the `header` is added to the request (without using ssl)?

Comment: Without ssl setting, Test Request having blank header only.

<soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Header>

I have removed SSL settings code and run the program to print test request.

Comment: @Rao - My keystore file extension type was "File", this will creating issue?

Comment: Can you try setting `Authenticate-Pre-emptive`?

Comment: @Rao - Can you help me here, how to set "Authenticate-Pre-emptive"?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rao!
   Authenticate-Pre-emptive resolved this issue. Now am getting a response.
https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html
Also removed the SoapUI.getSettings() codes from java code.

Comment: Ok, you want me to put that as Answer, so that it can be accepted as answer?

Comment: No @Rao!
I have accepting your answer is correct!
Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding it as answer based on the comments.

Set `Authenticate-Pre-emptive` to true.

This can be done either thru programming or from the SoapUI tool (Menu : File -> Preferences)